# Word for the best way to move from point A to B?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, terminology

Is there a word for the action of moving through the easiest path?  I've found "desire path" or "trail blazing", which comes close to the concept I'm looking for, but it lacks any amount of poetry.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To give context, I'm a physicist working with my team on publishing work that strongly revolves around paths of least resistance. None of us are necessarily experts in the field of English and are hoping to describe new principles in a way that doesn't require saying "the **path of least resistance** transition principle" or "the **path of least resistance** gravitation principle."

Comment: Are you talking about [the path of least resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_of_least_resistance), or about navigating that path?

Comment: Generally, "shortest path", "quickest way", or something of that nature.  There is no single idiom.

Comment: You need to explain your context a bit better.  (Your question could be closed because you have not provided such context.)

Comment: *Trailblazing* is hardly "moving through the easiest path".

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, the path of least resistance is indeed what I'm looking for, but I'm hoping there is a more succinct term that describes this.  To give context, I'm a physicist working with my team on publishing work that strongly revolves around paths of least resistance.  None of us are necessarily experts in the field of English and are hoping to describe new principles in a way that doesn't require saying "the path of least resistance transition principal" or "the path of least resistance gravitation principle."

Comment: ... But there seems no easier way.

Comment: A Google search for **path of least resistance PLR** shows that a number of people use the acronym.  Presumably they explain it early in their document. You could then say things like *PLR transition principle* and *PLR gravitation principle*.

Comment: Also consider "optimal pathway(s)."

Comment: Please include an example sentence. All single word requests require you to show how it will be used.

Comment: "Geodesic" works on a global scale, though its poetic appeal may be to special tastes.

Comment: @badbrahmin In physics, you might consider *minimum entropy*. If you provide more context, e.g. a short paragraph containing (a placeholder for) the term, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: I like [***geodesic***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity) — it’s used in general relativity to refer to a path through spacetime; possibly involving [least action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action). The physics is way beyond me, and we still don’t really know what the OP is talking about, so it’s hard to tell whether this is a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

The OP, who is a physicist, asks:

> Is there a word for the action of moving through the easiest path?
>   I've found "desire path" or "trail blazing", which comes close to the
>   concept I'm looking for, but it lacks any amount of **poetry**.
>   (emphasis added}.

I suggest ***the primrose path***, which comes from Shakespeare.  A problem with my answer is immediately obvious in the last six words in this definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primrose_path):

> The primrose path refers to a life of ease and pleasure, or to a
>   **course of action that seems easy and appropriate** but can actually end
>   in calamity. (emphasis added).

If I knew how to put the last six words in tiny type, I would have. But physicists have had no problem with co-opting English words and assigning completely different meanings to them:  [color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_charge), [charm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charm_quark), [flavor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_(particle_physics)).  Thus, I see no reason why the OP physicist could not co-opt the **primrose path** and change its meaning to omit the bad consequences of tripping along it.

From [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/289325.html)

> Ophelia:
>
> I shall the effect of this good lesson keep,
>
> As watchman to my heart. But, good my brother,
>
> Do not, as some ungracious pastors do,
>
> Show me the steep and thorny way to heaven;
>
> Whiles, like a puff'd and reckless libertine,
>
> Himself the primrose path of dalliance treads,
>
> And recks not his own rede

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you're looking for is ***least action***:

> [**least
> action**](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-principle-of-least-action-in-laymans-terms)
>
> In nature a system is forced to evolve in a way that [requires] the
> least possible action, [and] thus the least energy available to it.

You may be seeking an analogy of this principle, more or less.